# how can i access adobe AIR’s embedded SQLite database? I need to backup/export snippely (an air application)

Tags: sqlite, air

I have a air application called [snippley](http://code.google.com/p/snippely/)

All i want is to get to the data (my snippets) and export them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files will be stored in a directory called `Local Store`. Look for a "*.db" file (or "*.rdb"). You can either back up this file or zip up the contents of the entire directory. Best to keep your backups outside of `Local Store`

On Windows:
`c:/user name/Application Data/applicationID.publisherID/Local Store/`

On Mac:
`/Users/user name/Library/Preferences/applicationID.publisherID/Local Store/`

On Linux:
`/home/user name/.appdata/applicationID.publisherID/Local Store/`

There are a number of applications that allow you to look inside the SQLite database. I am presently using MesaSQLite.

Comment: Thanks, I have a mac and i don't find it in the Library/Preferences/ folder, Where else can it be?

Comment: Are you looking in your user folder or in the root folder. On my mac, it would be in `/Users/andrew/Library/Preferences/[appid.pubid]/Local Store/`. The folder won't be called `applicationID.publisherID`. It will have a name like `com.mootools.snippely` or something like that. You have to search it out.